# google ads api doesn't return rows with null columns

Tags: java, scala, protocol-buffers, google-ads-api

Migrating from AdWords to GoogleAds api.

Querying search_term_view:

```
val googleAdsClient: GoogleAdsClient = GoogleAdsClient.newBuilder()
  .setCredentials(credential)
  .setDeveloperToken(developerToken)
  .setLoginCustomerId(loginCustomerId.toLong)
  .build()
   
val svc = googleAdsClient.getLatestVersion.createGoogleAdsServiceClient()

val query = s"""
  SELECT 
    segments.keyword.info.text
    ,search_term_view.search_term
    ,segments.date
  FROM search_term_view
  WHERE segments.date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-01'
"""

svc.search(customerId, query).iteratePages().asScala.foreach { page =>
  page.iterateAll().asScala.foreach { row =>
    //row processing
  }
}
```

The issue is that svc.search() skips rows, if one of columns is null.
So getting results like

```
text1,term1
text2,term2
```

While same request to Adwords api returns results like

```
text1,term1
text2,term2
--,term3
```

Haven't found anything about nulls ignoring in docs.

Using latest google ads v10 lib:
"com.google.api-ads"   % "google-ads"                   % "17.0.1"

Comment: As this seems to be a discrepancy between the existing and recommended libraries, I think you'd be best placed filing an issue on Google's repo for the library or raising this on its forums. https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Received response from google team:

"Using [segments](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v10/segments?hl=en) fields in your query may result in fewer records being returned. This behavior is further explained in this [section](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/reporting/segmentation?hl=en#selectability_between_segments_and_metrics) of our [segmentation](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/reporting/segmentation?hl=en) guide. If no values can be associated to the segments field that is included in the SELECT clause, then no records will also be returned for it.

In addition, zero metrics records may also not be returned when segments fields are used as per this [other guide](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/reporting/zero-metrics?hl=en#exclude_zero_metrics_by_segmenting)."